# How can i color a selected item in a listbox ? To color only the selected item text when clicking the mouse right button

Tags: c#

It's working in general but since i want to make it color the item only when making right click on the mouse right button it's not working since when im showing/open the listBox it's first going to the DrawItem event:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);

            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                isColor = true;
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isColor == true)
            {
                if (e.Index < 0) return;
                //if the item state is selected them change the back color 
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                    e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                              e.Font,
                                              e.Bounds,
                                              e.Index,
                                              e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                              e.ForeColor,
                                              Color.Red);//Choose the color

                // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
                e.DrawBackground();
                // Draw the current item text
                e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            }
        }
```

I used a flag isColor but since it's first going to the DrawItem event this code is not working good.
Since isColor is flase now in the first time.

EDIT:

Two thing more i need.

1. When clicking the left mouse button on an item it will be marked with regular Blue as before.
2. When clicking on the right mouse button on an item it will be colored in Red.
3. To enable multiple chocies so if i click on right mouse it will keep the other items that already in Red so i can select many items to be in Red.

Comment: Doesn't DrawItem run for each item in the list?  You would need to capture   the item clicked on, and have logic that checks if the current item being drawn is the same item as the one clicked on...

Answer (score 0):

OnDrawItem is called for every item in the list.  and you are coloring every item red.  You need to check to see if the item that needs drawn is the selected item (if I remember correctly that would be `e.Selected`) and if it is then color it red, otherwise color it something else.. perhaps `SystemColors.Window`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex == e.index)
{
....
}
```

Comment: keyboardP dupilcated link example is working. The problem is that i want to color each item only when the user click on an item with the mouse right button. So i tried to use a flag but the problem is that when i show/open the listBox it's first going to the DrawItem event. I just updated my question with it.